# hadoop ImportTsv: Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Hello everyone I am trying to import a csv file into a hadoop environment installed on a docker container based on ubuntu.

### `emp_data.csv`

```
empno,ename,designation,manager,hire_date,sal,deptno
7369,SMITH,CLERK,7902,12/17/2016,18000,20
7499,ALLEN,SALESMAN,7698,2/20/2017,16000,30
7521,WARD,SALESMAN,7698,2/22/2017,12500,30
7566,TURNER,MANAGER,7839,4/2/2017,29750,20
7654,MARTIN,SALESMAN,7698,9/28/2017,12500,30
7698,MILLER,MANAGER,7839,5/1/2017,28500,30
7782,CLARK,MANAGER,7839,6/9/2017,24500,10
7788,SCOTT,ANALYST,7566,12/9/2018,30000,20
7839,KING,PRESIDENT,NULL,11/17/2017,50000,10
7844,TURNER,SALESMAN,7698,9/8/2017,15000,30
7876,ADAMS,CLERK,7788,1/12/2019,11000,20
7900,JAMES,CLERK,7698,12/3/2017,10000,30
7902,FORD,ANALYST,7566,12/3/2017,30000,20
7934,MILLER,CLERK,7782,1/23/2018,13000,10
```

However when I try to import the file `emp_data.csv` I get the following error:

```
2022-11-15 16:27:56,930 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1622)) - Running job: job_1668529482165_0001
2022-11-15 16:28:03,980 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1643)) - Job job_1668529482165_0001 running in uber mode : false
2022-11-15 16:28:03,981 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1650)) -  map 0% reduce 0%
2022-11-15 16:28:03,992 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1663)) - Job job_1668529482165_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1668529482165_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1668529482165_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2022-11-15 16:28:03.327]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1668529482165_0001_02_000001
Exit code: 1

[2022-11-15 16:28:03.329]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.


[2022-11-15 16:28:03.329]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.


For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://62b179bbc732:8088/cluster/app/application_1668529482165_0001 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
2022-11-15 16:28:04,004 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1668)) - Counters: 0
```

So I tried to view the logs from the management interface and I notice this error:

```
2022-11-15 16:28:02,427 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil: Updating Configuration
2022-11-15 16:28:02,519 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Executing with tokens: [Kind: YARN_AM_RM_TOKEN, Service: , Ident: (appAttemptId { application_id { id: 1 cluster_timestamp: 1668529482165 } attemptId: 2 } keyId: 1699913562)]
2022-11-15 16:28:02,547 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2022-11-15 16:28:02,547 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2022-11-15 16:28:02,559 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Using mapred newApiCommitter.
2022-11-15 16:28:02,560 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: OutputCommitter set in config null
2022-11-15 16:28:02,605 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputCommitter
2022-11-15 16:28:02,984 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster failed in state INITED
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$GetFileInfoRequestProto cannot be cast to com.google.protobuf.Message
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:122)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:965)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1753)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1750)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1765)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1760)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceInit(MRAppMaster.java:317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$6.run(MRAppMaster.java:1760)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1757)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1691)
2022-11-15 16:28:02,986 ERROR [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
```

### Additional information

Here are the configuration files of my hadoop environment

#### `core-site.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hdoop/tmpdata</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

#### `hdfs-site.xml`

```xml
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hdoop/dfsdata/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hdoop/dfsdata/datanode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

#### `mapred-site.xml`

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

#### `yarn-site.xml`

```xml
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>127.0.0.1</value>
    </property>
    <property> 
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
        <value>0.0.0.0:8088</value>
      </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
        <value>0</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.env-whitelist</name>
        <value>JAVA_HOME,HADOOP_COMMON_HOME,HADOOP_HDFS_HOME,HADOOP_CONF_DIR,CLASSPATH_PERPEND_DISTCACHE,HADOOP_YARN_HOME,HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

For the versions used
**Ubuntu**: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
**Hadoop**: Hadoop 3.3.4
**Java**: OpenJdk 8

Comment: Unclear why you have YARN logs to "import" anything. Just use `hdfs dfs -put`. You don't need YARN here